# Recursive parser using split in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, parsing, recursion

I have an algorithm where the user will enter a string and I will parse it into an array of 2+ dimensions. So, for example, the user can enter 1,2,3;4,5,6 and set the text to be parsed by the semicolon and the comma. The first pass through will create an array with 2 entries. The second pass through will create a 3 entry array in both prior spots.

The user can add or remove the number of text items to be used to parse the original string such as the semicolon or comma, meaning the resulting array can have as many dimensions as parsing items.

This doesn't seem like a difficult problem, but I have run into some snags.

Here is my code so far.

```
vm.parsers = [';', ','];

vm.inputString = "1,2,3,4,5;6,7,8,9,10";

function parseDatasetText( )
{   
    vm.real = vm.parseMe( vm.inputString, 0);
};


function parseMe( itemToParse, indexToParse )
{   
    if ( indexToParse < vm.parsers.length )
    {
        console.log('Parsing *'+itemToParse+'* with '+vm.parsers[indexToParse]);
        var tempResults = itemToParse.split( vm.parsers[indexToParse] );
        for (var a=0; a<tempResults.length; a++)
        {
            console.log('Pushing '+tempResults[a]);
            tempResults[a] = vm.parseMe( tempResults[a], parseInt( indexToParse ) + 1 )
            console.log('This value is '+tempResults[a]);
        }
    }else
    {
        console.log('Returning '+itemToParse);
        return itemToParse
    }
};
```

As you can see from the console logs, the algorithm spits out an undefined after the last parse, and the final answer is undefined.

Maybe I just haven't slept enough, but I was thinking that the array would recursively populate via the splits?

Thanks

Comment: I think it will only have 2 dimensions since there will only be two kinds of delimiters in your string from what i understand.

Comment: @HarshulPandav I think Joshua would like to have dynamic delimiters and the requirement is the function should be able to return 2+ dimensions if there is more delimiters.

Comment: In that case the delimiters need a weight so that we can know which one to chose for the first dimension, then second and so on. Unless the sequence of delimiters in the vm.parsers array is to be taken in to consideration

Comment: @Joshua needs to confirm whether the delimiter array can have more entries.

Comment: As per my understanding, the weight will be determined by their 'index' since the parsers[0] should be useless after the first loop and so on

Comment: @Joshua check this out: `function parseDatasetText(){
  var fn = vm.parsers.reduceRight(
    (nextFn, delimiter) => v => String(v).split(delimiter).map(nextFn), 
    v => v
  );
  
  return fn( vm.inputString );
}`

Comment: Yes, as it says in the question, the user can add or remove from the array of delimiters ending up with an n-dimensional array. The algorithm starts at the 0 index of the parsers array and iterates from 0 to the length of the array. I think that Zay Lau answered it, but I am still checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple recursive function like the following (here an example with 3 different delimiters):

```js
function multiSplit(xs, delimiters) {
  if (!delimiters.length) return xs;
  return xs.split(delimiters[0]).map(x => multiSplit(x, delimiters.slice(1)));
}

data = '1:10,2:20,3:30;4:40,5:50,6:60';
res = multiSplit(data, [';', ',', ':']);
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Awesome, the map function is always faster

Answer (score 2):

```
function parseDatasetText(){ 
    //composing parser from right to left into a single function 
    //that applies them from left to right on the data
    var fn = vm.parsers.reduceRight( 
        (nextFn, delimiter) => v => String(v).split(delimiter).map(nextFn), 
        v => v
    );

    return fn( vm.inputString ); 
}
```

Don't know what else to add.

Answer (score 1):

The following function should suit your requirements, please let me know if not

```
var parsers = [';', ',', ':'],
    inputString = "1:a,2:b,3:c,4:d,5:e;6:f,7:g,8:h,9:i,10:j",
    Result = [];

function Split(incoming) {
    var temp = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < parsers.length; i++)
        if (incoming.indexOf(parsers[i]) >= 0) {
            temp = incoming.split(parsers[i]);
            break;
        }

    if (temp == null) return incoming;

    var outgoing = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
        outgoing[outgoing.length] = Split(temp[i])

    return outgoing;
}

Result = Split(inputString);
```

try it on https://jsfiddle.net/cgy7nre1/

### Edit 1 -

Added another inputString and another set of parsers: https://jsfiddle.net/cgy7nre1/1/

Comment: This appears to work, let me look at it a little more and verify. What was wrong with what I was doing?

Comment: @JoshuaFoxworth - Please upvote and accept the answer if it was useful to you.

Comment: @JoshuaFoxworth That could be silly, but seems like you forget to `return tempResults;`

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?

```
var inputString = "1,2,3,4,5;6,7,8,9,10";

var array=inputString.split(';');
for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    array[i]=array[i].split(',');
}

console.log(array);
```